# Can I assign 2 object for 1 definition in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, object

For example, I have the following data

```
A : {  name: "Ball",
       color: { 
                out : ["red","black","green"],
                in : ["white","pink"]
               },
     }
```

I want to have another object to call with the same definition. Can I do this?

```
 A, B : {  name: "Ball",
           color: { 
                    out : ["red","black","green"],
                    in : ["white","pink"]
                   },
         }
```

Comment: It's not possible, but you can do something like this. Create `A` object and the assign it to `B`. e.g. `A = {}; B = A`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're asking for the syntax to declare 2 fields with the same value, no you cannot do that. You can however declare a separate variable and point both fields at that variable.

```
const myBall = {
  name: "Ball",
  color: {
    out: ["red", "black", "green"],
    in: ["white", "pink"]
  }
};

const myObject = {
  A: myBall,
  B: myBall
};
```

or if you're looking to create two discrete objects, you could write a function to create a new one for you.

```
const createMyBall = () => ({
  name: "Ball",
  color: {
    out: ["red", "black", "green"],
    in: ["white", "pink"]
  }
});

const myObject = {
  A: createMyBall(),
  B: createMyBall()
};
```

Answer (score 0):

assing to object

```
var a, b;
a = b =
```

```js
var a, b;
a = b =
{  name: "Ball",
   color: 
   { 
      out : ["red","black","green"],
      in : ["white","pink"]
    },
};
console.log(a);

console.log(b);
```